# Where is swagger cli on windows

Tags: npm-install, swagger-codegen

I just ran 'npm install -g swagger' on my Windows 8 box and it seems to have run successfully, but when I try and run the swagger CLI, as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger, it doesn't know where it's at.

How do I get to that tool?

Answer (score 1):

For windows 10 swagger gets installed as A NODE module under

C:\Users`your name`\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\swagger

you will also see the following entries under :

C:\Users`your name`\AppData\Roaming\npm
- swagger.cmd
- swagger-project.cmd

hope this helps